# External links add domain to front of link, even when using http://

Tags: php, html, url, hyperlink, href

**Problem:** External links have our domain name to the front of the link.

**In database the following string is stored:**
`To learn more about Rich Habits <a href=”http://www.externaldomain.com”>click here.</a>`

**In our PHP File we echo the string as such:**
`</p><?php echo Author::getAuthorBio( $post->author1 ) ?></p>`

**The resulting HTML from a browser is as such:**
`<p>To learn more about Rich Habits <a href=”http://www.externaldomain.com”>click here.</a></p>`

**But, when clicking on link, the url is:**
mydomain.com/”http://www.externaldomain.com”

How do I make link correct?

Comment: Then there's something we're not quite seeing here.  Maybe some javascript or CSS modifying the link?  If the HTML source has the correct link, then it's not the PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to quote the value of the attribute with `”` instead of `"`. The `”` is not a valid character for quoting attributes in HTML, so it is being treated as part of the URL.

Since `”http://` is not a valid URL scheme, it is being treated as a relative URL.

Replace the `”` with `"`.

Your problem is most likely caused by writing your HTML in something other than a text editor. Word processors have a habit of replacing straight quotes with typographic quotes. This is mistake when dealing with code instead of English.

Comment: Thanks, works now! You're right. The string was originally in a word doc,. I thought copying it to notepad and then copying that to the database would work. Do you have a recommendation of how to convert? I expect all our writers to write using a Word Processor.

Comment: Edit > Find & Replace in most programs

Answer (score 1):

Your `”` around the href attribute are not double quotes.  They are special characters.  Replace them with `"` and it'll fix it.